# HTML innerHtml doesn't update after function updates

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am working on interview practice questions and running into an innerHTML that has a predefined HTML element with a binding parameter that is getting passed.

```
var foo = false;
function define(x) {
    var foo = true;
 }
 define(true);
 document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML= "'foo' is equal to '" + foo + "'.";

 <span id="foo"></span>
```

I've tried a few different things like creating the element in the javaScript, trying to set with '.textContent = "" +foo + ""', making the function use inner value return{ foo:true} with foo = define(true).foo; and a couple others though value of foo is still false. What sets this here?

Comment: var is function scoped, if you remove the `var` in your function, then you'll be updating the global `foo` variable

Comment: @NickParsons JQuery newbie. Thanks that worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Foo is false because the internal foo variable in the function is out of the scope of the block where you use "the outer" foo.

```
 var foo = false;
 function define(x) {
    var foo = true;
    return foo; // function should return a value
 }
 foo = define(true); // this will retrieve the value from the function
 document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML= "'foo' is equal to '" + foo + "'.";
```

Comment: Thanks this does function but NickParsons was better concise removing the var keyword with using the scope definition as intended by JavaScript.